# Using libXml2 in C++ with Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, libxml2

I'm having a problem getting C++ code to compile properly in Netbeans, specifically code that deals with libXml2. I downloaded libXml2, put it in the include folder and I know that the code itself compiles fine without any libxml2 references in it, however, when I add the following functions:

```
void XmlParser::processNode(xmlTextReaderPtr reader){
    const xmlChar *name, *value;
    name = xmlTextReaderConstName(reader);
    if (name == NULL)
    name = BAD_CAST "--";

    value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader);

    printf("%d %d %s %d %d",
        xmlTextReaderDepth(reader),
        xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader),
        name,
        xmlTextReaderIsEmptyElement(reader),
        xmlTextReaderHasValue(reader));
    if (value == NULL)
    printf("\n");
    else {
        if (xmlStrlen(value) > 40)
            printf(" %.40s...\n", value);
        else
        printf(" %s\n", value);
    }
}
void XmlParser::streamFile(const char *filename) {
    xmlTextReaderPtr reader;
    int ret;
    reader = xmlReaderForFile(filename, NULL, 0);
    if (reader != NULL) {
        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        while (ret == 1) {
            //processNode(reader);
            ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        }
        xmlFreeTextReader(reader);
        if (ret != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s : failed to parse\n", filename);
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", filename);
    }
}
```

I get the following result when I click build:

build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/XmlParser.o: In function `ZN9XmlParser11processNodeEP14_xmlTextReader':
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:26: undefined reference to`xmlTextReaderConstName'
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:30: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstValue'
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:37: undefined reference to`xmlTextReaderHasValue'
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:37: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderIsEmptyElement'
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:37: undefined reference to`xmlTextReaderNodeType'
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:37: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderDepth'
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:41: undefined reference to`xmlStrlen'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/XmlParser.o: In function `ZN9XmlParser10streamFileEPKc':
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:51: undefined reference to`xmlReaderForFile'
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:53: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderRead'
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:56: undefined reference to`xmlTextReaderRead'
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\XmlBallotParser/XmlParser.cpp:58: undefined reference to `xmlFreeTextReader'

Which suggests that I have some sort of an issue compiling the program using libXml2. I saw that someone right [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=486186) had the same error, and that the answer to this problem is correctly setting up the argument for compiling the program, however, I cannot figure out how to do this in NetBeans/Windows. I think what I need is details on how to actually get the arguments right. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: NOTE: I know that the code itself is also correct because I for it from here: http://xmlsoft.org/examples/reader1.c

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lxml2` (gcc) or `libxml2.lib` (visual studio) to your linker.

Comment: I have minGW so im not entirely sure how to do that. If I install cygwin, would that have gcc?